# a problem of sequence of convergence of Real analysis

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $f_n(x) = a_nx^2+b_nx+c_n :[0,1] \to R$ be a uniformly convergent sequence of quadratic polynomials with real coefficients.prove that the convergence of  $f_n(x)$  is a polynomial of degree at most two

Answer (score 1):

Since $f_n$ converges uniformly to some $f$, it converges pointwise to $f$. This means that for any $x\in[0, 1]$ we have
\begin{equation}
f(x)\equiv\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n x^2+b_nx +c_n= ax^2+bx+c
\end{equation} Therefore, the highest degree is at most $2$ if $a\neq 0$.